# unix command to redirect logs to a file for specific duration

Tags: shell, unix

I am running an application through shell script. 
I want the console logs to be redirected to a file but during startup alone( say for first 10 mins). After that I don't want logs to be written into the file ?

Can this be achieved ?

Comment: Depends on your application. What application are you using and how do you invoke it?

Comment: I am starting java app from shell script. I want to know whether it can be done unix redirection command ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `perl`, this one-liner should do it:

```
command | perl -pe '
  BEGIN { open(LOG, ">log") || die $!; select LOG; $|=1; $end=time+1 }
  select STDOUT if (time>=$end)'
```

`perl -pe` tells Perl to echo lines from standard input to the selected output in a loop. The `BEGIN` block opens the log file (unbuffered, so you see the messages in the file without waiting for the buffer to fill up) before the loop starts, selecting it as output and setting up the end time to ten minutes (600 secs) from now. The execution then simply prints to the log file before the initial period, and to the standard output afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm using shell script.

Comment: @user1083206 This one-liner (ok, three-liner) is specifically designed to be used from within a shell script - note the pipe syntax - so I am not proposing that you replace your whole script with Perl. Think of it like invoking `awk`, `sed` or `grep`, but with more punch. :)